# Inserting new values combined with a select query using prepared statements

Tags: mysql, select, insert

What is the correct syntax for inserting new values combined with a select query using prepared statements?

What I have doesn't work.

```
INSERT INTO productsUsers
    (product, userId)
VALUES
    (?, SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `INSERT INTO`...`SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO productsUsers (product, userId)
SELECT ?,  id 
  FROM users 
 WHERE username = ?;
```

If you want to avoid duplicated `id`'s you could use a `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause. Check out [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/insert-select.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
INSERT INTO productsUsers(product, userId)
SELECT ?,  id 
  FROM users 
  WHERE username = ?)
```

Check this out for [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)

The syntax is:-

> INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
>
> ```
> [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
> SELECT ...
> [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col_name=expr, ... ]
> ```